# How to do transclusion md-menu items into Material md-menu

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

How to include menu-items into child components
See example:
**dropdown.component.html**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button md-icon-button
            [mdMenuTriggerFor]="dropMenu">
        <i class="glyphicon glyph-more"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<md-menu #navMenu="dropMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <ng-content></ng-content> 
    <!-- after rendering I'm able to see all buttons, 
         and interact with them my mouse click.
         But they not accessible with keyboard -->
</md-menu>
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="header">
  ...
  <dropdown>
    <button md-menu-item>Button 1</button>
    <button md-menu-item>Button 2</button>
    <button md-menu-item>Button 3</button>
  </dropdown>
  ...
</div>
```

It works, but not as expected.
I can see that items, and menu working by click, but I'm unable to use keyboard for items access.
Also in *dropdown.component.ts* if I get access to `MdMenu` component via `@ViewChild('navMenu')` it shows me 0 items
`this.mdMenu.items // 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MdMenu` directive uses `@ContentChildren` to get list of `MdMenuItem`.

```
@ContentChildren(MdMenuItem) items: QueryList<MdMenuItem>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  this._keyManager = new FocusKeyManager(this.items).withWrap();
  this._tabSubscription = this._keyManager.tabOut.subscribe(() => this._emitCloseEvent());
}
```

As `ContentChildren` works only for the component-owner of template your menu directive will always have `0` items.

Workaround could be as follows

**dropdown.component.ts**

```
...
export class DropDownComponent {
  @ViewChild(MdMenu) menu: MdMenu;

  @ContentChildren(MdMenuItem) items: QueryList<MdMenuItem>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.menu.items = this.items;
    this.menu.ngAfterContentInit();
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/IhCC9voZKF8e4AjVXtO3?p=preview)**

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8937
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16299

Comment: Thank you!
This is the solution.